# How to read json data in pig?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have the following type of json file:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

I am trying to execute the following pig script to load json data

```
A = load 'pigdemo/employeejson.json' using JsonLoader ('employees:{(firstName:chararray)},{(lastName:chararray)}');
```

getting error!!

> Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input:
>   expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source:
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1553f9b2; line: 1, column: 1])  at
>   [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1553f9b2; line: 1, column: 29]

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: #Satya I have update the question

Comment: A = load 'pigdemo/employeejson.json' using JsonLoader ('employees:{(firstName:chararray),(lastName:chararray)}'); try this one!!

Comment: 2016-09-23 07:38:02,032 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2016-09-23 07:38:02,040 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1474637915471_0007_m_000000_3 Info:Error: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7a91efc3; line: 1, column: 1])   this is the error message i am getting @Ankur

Comment: try tthis @Avijit : A = load 'pigdemo/employeejson.json' using JsonLoader ('employees':{(firstName:chararray)},{(lastName:chararray)});

Comment: same thing i have also written @satya what is the difference ?

Comment: Unable to read the single value also A = load 'pigdemo/employeejson.json' using JsonLoader ('employees':{(firstName:chararray)}');

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE 2016-09-23 07:38:02,032 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2016-09-23 07:38:02,040 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1474637915471_0007_m_000000_3 Info:Error: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7a91efc3; line: 1, column: 1])

Comment: can you change the input file ? - remove the first and last line ?

Answer (score 1):

First the reason that you see `Unexpected end-of-input` is because each recode should be in 1 line - like this :

`{"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}`

Now - since each row is employees list run the next command

```
A = load '$flurryData' using JsonLoader ('employees:bag {t:tuple(firstName:chararray, lastName:chararray)}');
describe A;
dump A;
```

Give the next output

```
A: {employees: {t: (firstName: chararray,lastName: chararray)}}

({(John,Doe),(Anna,Smith),(Peter,Jones)})
```

Hope this help !